# ActiveMQ Fail over issue with MySQL DB

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using activeMQ with fail over protocol and mySql Db as data storage.When i start both broker; one broker is active(as master) and other broker (as slave) become inactive but after certain time slave wake up become master.I am unable to find anything why this happen.

Comment: Have you checked the logs to see if the first broker is failing after some time, which causes the second one to become active? Or are you saying that both brokers are active at the same time?

Comment: both broker active at same time . but we upgrade  the active mq version from 5.6 to 5.14 now only single broker is active

Comment: That's good to know. Please add an answer below with your fix and mark it as accepted for future reference.